# Simple Ajax request in Yii not working

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am trying to make a simple ajax request in Ajax in Yii

I have my view file views/items/index.php and a controller file controllers/ItemsController.php

I have inserted a link in my view file

```
    echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    'Test request',          // the link body (it will NOT be HTML-encoded.)
    array('ajax/reqTest01'), // the URL for the AJAX request. If empty, it is assumed to be the current URL.
    array(
        'update'=>'#req_res'
    )
);
?>

<div id="req_res">...</div>
```

I have this code in my controller file

```
public function actionReqTest01() {
    echo date('H:i:s');
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

But Nothing is happening it is giving error 404 (as checked in chrome network tab)

Comment: Works fine for me. Is actionReqTest01() inside AjaxController.php?

Comment: I dont want it separately. I am using it in a model's index view so i have placed this controller action inside the controller for that model is it wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Another controller named AjaxController.php
write this code in that.

```
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
 public function actionReqTest01() {
  echo date('H:i:s');
  Yii::app()->end();
 }
}
```